# Add 60 days to predefined date string

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a predefined date getting pulled from a database that looks like this: `2014-06-17` and I need to add 60 days to that specified day.

My code is as below: but it currently echoes out the same day for both result and accept.

What is wrong?

```
$result = $this->employment->verify($data);

        echo $result.'<br/>';

        $accept = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+60 days", $result));

        echo $accept.'<br/>';

        return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` needs a UNIX timestamp as the second argument:

```
$accept = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+60 days", strtotime($result)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result ='2014-06-17';

$accept = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result. ' + 60 days'));

echo $accept;
```

That should work, I hope.

Comment: wont work with his current $result variable

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for the feedback, but why don't you think it will work?

Comment: becuse i ran it :-) http://codepad.viper-7.com/6XgAl5

Comment: @Dagon appreciate your feedback, this should work, I tested it this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result ='2014-06-17';

echo $result.'<br/>';

$accept = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+60 days", strtotime($result)));

echo $accept.'<br/>';
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/rQVnmB